# How to merge overlapping intervals in pandas dataframe and count the number of merges

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
      start          end         score        machine
0  1631816145    1631816312       0.5            1
1  1631817088    1631817228       0.6            1
2  1631819637    1631819844       0.2            1
3  1631816844    1631817030       0.7            2
4  1631817073    1631817225       0.4            2
5  1631818103    1631818261       0.7            2
```

`start` and `end` columns are just unix timestamps. How can I merge the overlapping time intervals and keep a count of the number of merges per interval? For instance, in the example above, 2nd row and 2nd last row should merge into one interval, their scores should be combined i.e., 0.6 + 0.7 = 1.3, and the `count` should be 2 (number of intervals merged).

At the end, I want to keep the overlapping intervals that appear in *most* machines.

Comment: If you could paste your data as text and format as code instead of pasting a picture, we could copy it and try to help you.

Comment: Edited my question. Thanks

Comment: I've submitted an answer below. But I just realise that could one row fall totally within another row ?  eg s1 > s2 and e1  < e2 ?  If this is the case, then I think it would be easier just to check whether any of the start is within the start/end of the other and do the same for the end.

Answer (score 0):

I've adopted the approach from another very good answer [determine the range of a value using a look up table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69462119/determine-the-range-of-a-value-using-a-look-up-table).  It handles the sample data given in the question.

Code:

```
 df = pd.read_excel('Miscel.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet3') df
```

Output:

```
start   end score   machine
0   1631816145  1631816312  0.5 1
1   1631817088  1631817228  0.6 1
2   1631819637  1631819844  0.2 1
3   1631816844  1631817030  0.7 2
4   1631817073  1631817225  0.4 2
5   1631818103  1631818261  0.7 2
```

Code:

```
s1 = df['start'].to_numpy()
s2 = df['start'].to_numpy()[:,None]
e1 = df['end'].to_numpy()
e2 = df['end'].to_numpy()[:,None]
```

Code:

```
a = (s1 >= s2) & (s1 <= e2)   # start between another start/end
a
```

Output:

```
array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True]])
```

Code:

```
b = (e1 >= e2)  # end start another end
b
```

Output:

```
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False, False,  True]])
```

Code:

```
c = a & b     #  AND logic => start between another start/end and end after end
c
```

Output:

```
array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True]])
```

Code:

```
d = c | c.T  # create mask for calculating scores
d
```

Output:

```
array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True]])
```

Code:

```
e = d.sum(axis=1)   # calculate count 
e
```

Output:

```
array([1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1])
```

Code:

```
df['count'] = e
df
```

Output:

```
    start   end score   machine count
0   1631816145  1631816312  0.5 1   1
1   1631817088  1631817228  0.6 1   2
2   1631819637  1631819844  0.2 1   1
3   1631816844  1631817030  0.7 2   1
4   1631817073  1631817225  0.4 2   2
5   1631818103  1631818261  0.7 2   1
```

Code:

```
score1 = (df['score'].to_numpy() * (c | c.T)).sum(axis=1)
```

Code:

```
df['score1'] = score1
df
```

Output:

```
    start   end score   machine count   score1
0   1631816145  1631816312  0.5 1   1   0.5
1   1631817088  1631817228  0.6 1   2   1.0
2   1631819637  1631819844  0.2 1   1   0.2
3   1631816844  1631817030  0.7 2   1   0.7
4   1631817073  1631817225  0.4 2   2   1.0
5   1631818103  1631818261  0.7 2   1   0.7
```